# Is it ok to omit “the” in front of plural nouns?

Tags: articles

What is the difference between

1. The problems with **the** current education systems

Vs.

2. The problems with current education systems

Is the second one grammatical?

The reason why I think a “the” is necessary in front of “current” is that when I use “current” in front of “education systems”, I am making it specific. Do you think this logic is correct? Or is it ok to omit the “the” in front of “current”?

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include ***the*** in your example noun phrase, and the choice makes no difference whatsoever to the meaning. Note that you *must* include the article with singular ***system***, regardless of whether it's qualified by (syntactically optional) ***current*** and/or ***educational***.

Comment: I'd almost always use the definite article if the current education systems had already been listed. Otherwise. I'd use it pragmatically as a discourse 'lubricant' to hint at familiarity ('with which we're all familiar, of course').

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are grammatical. The first (using the definite article) is focused on specific current education systems, and readers are expected to understand from context which ones.

Without the article the example refers to current education systems in general.

Using the definite article without any context is awkward because it makes it difficult for a reader to work out which current education systems are being specifically referred to. A reader may think that the writer will be contrasting the current education systems to other systems, possibly including education systems that are not current.

In general, it is often correct to omit the definite article in front of plural nouns. However the presence or absence of the article will usually alter the meaning.

Comment: I disagree that the second form relates to education systems that are not current, it specifically mentions current systems. However it is more general than the first. The first will be referring to education systems in a certain context (perhaps a specific country like the UK, a wider area such as Europe or a conceptual classification like "advanced economies" or "developing countries"). The second, in contrast, would relate to education systems in general covering all countries, continents or conceptual classifications.

Comment: @BoldBen, that was not what I meant to say, so I have modified (and hopefully improved) my answer. I meant to say that adding "the" may suggest that the sentence has the silent continuation ... "that were not present with the older systems".

Comment: I don't think including ***the*** makes any difference *at all* in OP's context. The only way a determiner would affect things is if you'd already established a context identifying ***some*** educational systems (from different times, places, social groups, whatever), in which case you could use ***those*** or ***these*** to identify them. But not ***the***, which would always mean ***all***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, with no context I would expect "The problems with current education systems". If "the" was in there I would look for reasons why. I might conclude there is no reason why, or I might jump to the wrong conclusion, but I would look.

Comment: @Peter: Like I said - personally, I wouldn't give the presence / absence of the article a second thought. Apart from anything else, that might distract me from thinking about the implications of a *far* more significant "deviation from expectation" implied by plural ***systems***. Per [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+the+current+education+system%2Cwith+current+education+systems%2Cwith+the+current+education+systems&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) plural is relatively very uncommon.

Comment: ...given NGrams is dominated by the AmE corpus, there's obviously no significant US/UK usage split here based on the range of different ways education is provided in the two main Anglophone nations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, in Australia each state has its own education system, and there is a Catholic education system and a number of independent schools. In this context I didn't give the plural a second thought.

Comment: oic. So arguably your perspective (and thus your *answer*) is significantly affected by the fact that you're Australian. If you didn't even notice the plural as being at least *slightly* unusual, that might imply your reaction to the presence / absence of an article could also be relatively uncommon among "mainstream Anglophones" in general. In principle I think of Australian / Canadian / South African / etc. English as "mainstream" (*Indian* English being the archetypal "non-mainstream" version). But maybe this is a special case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142628/discussion-between-peter-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score -1):

1. The problems with the current education systems [in my country, in China, in the EU]. **the** refers to something specific that has been discussed earlier in the text.
   Vs.
2. The problems with current education systems [everywhere in the world, for example]. ***One could imagine saying that if one thought they all had some feature in common.***

The bees in the orchards in my county are not doing well.
Bees in the world are not doing well.

A "the" is always specific. A plural noun is always general.

Comment: The problem with downvoters is that often the don't get it.